# jqGrid v4 - dynamic column not working

Tags: jquery, dynamic, jqgrid

Controller Code:

```
 public JsonResult GetGridColumn()
 {
    var jsonData = new
    {
       colNames = "['actname']",
       colModel = "[{ name: 'actionTaken'}]",
      };
      return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
  }
```

View Code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/GetForm/GetGridColumn",
        data: "",
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            colN = data.colNames;
            colM = data.colModel;
            $("#taskGrid").jqGrid({
                url: "someurl",
                datatype: 'jsonstring',
                mtype: 'POST',
                colNames: colN,
                colModel: colM,
                pager: jQuery('#pager'),
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
                height: '100%',
                viewrecords: true,
                width: 1250,
                jsonReader: {
                    cell: "",
                    id: "0"
                }
            })
        }
    });
});
```

I get colN  as ['actname']  and colM  as [{ name: 'actionTaken'}]. When I run the above script I get this error Length of colNames<> colModel!

Comment: try something like `var jsonData = new { colNames = new [] {"actname"}, colModel = new [] { new { name = "actionTaken" } }};` In any way `jsonData.colNames` and `jsonData.colModel` should be **arrays** and not strings. jqGrid verify that both arrays has the same number of elements, but you use `colNames` and `colModel` as strings and the test `if (p.colNames.length !== p.colModel.length) {` compares the length of the strings in your case. It's the reason of misunderstandable error message.

Comment: Thank you very much Oleg. I changed my jasonData as stated above and it worked!!

Comment: You are welcome! I posted the same information as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like

```
var jsonData = new {
        colNames = new [] {"actname"},
        colModel = new [] { new { name = "actionTaken" } }
    };
```

In any way `jsonData.colNames` and `jsonData.colModel` should be arrays and not strings. jqGrid verify that both arrays has the same number of elements, but you use `colNames` and `colModel` as strings and the test `if (p.colNames.length !== p.colModel.length) {` compares the length of the strings in your case. It's the reason of misunderstandable error message.